# Android Air startup at Boot time

Tags: android, air, startup, air-android

Is it possible to get an Android Air app to startup at Boot time.

Doing it in Java seems quite possible (see [Android 2.2: How to make an app to run automaticly on startup & how to make an app start another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554583/android-2-2-how-to-make-an-app-to-run-automaticly-on-startup-how-to-make-an-a)) but I am not sure how you
do the same thing in AS3.

James

Comment: The AIR application can start from a Startup/ or application launcher just like any other application, no?