# How to open other existing Android applications

Tags: android, button, click

Is it possible to open another application (like : BBM or LINE) when I click a button on my own application? Is there source code for this?

Comment: Search engines are your friends: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518407/android-starting-an-activity-for-a-different-third-party-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(/** Component information of the target app. */);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what is parameter of Component information of the target app ? where can I get it if I want to open application BBM or LINE ?

Comment: You need the package name and the class name of the app you want to open. package name is easy: it's listed in play store. class name is more tricky. but you can fetch it from `adb logcat` when starting the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch any application that is installed in your device using `Intent` call from your application. Only thing you need is the **Package name**.

```
Intent sendIntent =   getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package_name_for_corr_app");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

We can get Package name in many ways. One possible way is by using DDMS. When starting an app inside a connected device or emulator, its package name will be shown inside Logcat. or you can browse for package names using DDMS->file explorer.

Comment: where can I get package name ?

Comment: Edited answer. One another way is using `PackageManager`. That will be irrelevant for you.